# Using multiple jump start batteries

Tags: jump-start

I was recently caught out with a flat battery.  I want to buy a jump battery to make sure it doesn't happen again.  My car is a BMW 3 litre, 6 cylinder diesel that will need somewhere around 500-600 cranking amps.  All the jump batteries I can find here have only 300 cranking amps.  If I connect two of those batteries to my car at the same time, will that give me the 600 cranking amps I need?

Comment: Cant you use a battery-tender? Cheaper and your unused jump battery will probably go bad soon anyways. Or just get some jumper cables. Surely there is someone else with a car nearby should you need a jump-start once again?

Comment: The car is a 4WD and I am often in the bush.

Comment: Fit a second battery in the boot and use a split-charge system, then if you need to "help" the primary vehicle battery you can...

Comment: I am looking for an answer to my question about connecting multiple jump batteries. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to offer you a sensible solution, at least, better use of your money than your idea of buying two jump batteries... But your money, your choice.

Comment: In theory, two batteries in parallel will provide twice the current capability. However, mismatches between the batteries (different ages, charge level, manufacturers, etc.) will affect the result.

Comment: @mike65535 so any issues with 3 as proposed by the OP... if you fit a "good" split-charge system... but bored now.

Comment: Same issues with three or 'n' batteries but OP proposed two in total.

Comment: @mike65535 vehicle battery plus two jump batteries comes to 3 for me...

Comment: Ok,  three physical batteries,  including one dead one.  Since the issue was how well two paralleled jump batteries would work, and that's where the 600A would come from,  that's what I was dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can.  As long as you hook all positives together and all negatives together, the amperage stacks.  DO NOT CONNECT RED TO BLACK OR YOU WILL EITHER EXPLODE A BATTERY OR FRY YOUR ELECTRONICS

Comment: and you have the space to make reliable connections...

Comment: The amperage stacks in theory. In practice, the different resistance of the different battery hook-up connections means it won't stack very well at high currents. With 500A current, a resistance of 0.001 ohms will drop half a volt.

Comment: i didn't want to get into electrical theory since it wasn't necessary.  I won't claim my math is perfect, but e = 500 / .001 comes out to .17 volts.  An alternator won't notice the difference.